# Exchange data(messages) between robots in ROS1

Tags: ros, wifi, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together,

actually I have some rover running on ROS1 and want exchange data over messages between them e.g. to make a merged map.
They will all be connected to an access-point. Each rover should run his own roscore.
What are the possibilities to do that? Anyone did something like this before?

BTW: I'm aware that ROS2 is more suitable for that, but due to the ARM Hardware ROS2 will not work for me at the moment.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329845/exchange-data(messages)-between-robots-in-ros1/) by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2019-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds as though you want to use a ROS Multimaster setup between your rovers. There is a [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie/Tutorials/Setup%20a%20ROS%20master%20synchronization) about setting this up here.

Is there a reason why you need each rover to run their own `roscore`, for example do they have intermittent access to the shared Wi-Fi network?

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MrCheesecake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44078/mrcheesecake/) on 2019-08-02**:
I think it would be more reliable to run roscore localy on the rovers. They should be as autonomous as possible. For example they should continue to work if they lost connection to the AP or the master.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-08-02**:\

> I think it would be more reliable to run roscore localy on the rovers

and that is exactly what multimaster allows you to do.